# Manipulate bars from a chart

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I need to change the first and the last bars. As you can see, both bars are halfed due the limits of the chart.
Which class from Apache POI librar should I use to change that?[image]

This is the code which is drawing the chart

```
private ByteArrayInputStream generateFileDetails(List<ClientDataRequest> clientDataRequest, String metricName){

        ByteArrayOutputStream file = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try{
            try(XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()){
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(metricName);
                Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
                headerFont.setBold(true);
                headerFont.setUnderline(Font.U_SINGLE);
                CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
                headerCellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_40_PERCENT.getIndex());
                headerCellStyle.setFont(headerFont);

                XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
                XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 14, 10+ clientDataRequest.size());

                Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(anchor.getRow2()+1);
                headerRow.createCell(0).setCellValue("Client Name");
                headerRow.createCell(1).setCellValue("Value");

                for (int i = 0; i < headerRow.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
                    headerRow.getCell(i).setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < clientDataRequest.size(); i++) {
                    Row row = sheet.createRow(anchor.getRow2()+2+i);
                    row.createCell(0).setCellValue(clientDataRequest.get(i).getClientName());
                    sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
                    row.createCell(1).setCellValue(clientDataRequest.get(i).getValue());
                    sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);
                }

                XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
                chart.setTitleText(metricName);
                chart.setTitleOverlay(false);

                //XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
                //legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

                XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
                bottomAxis.setTitle("Client Name");
                XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
                leftAxis.setTitle("Value");
                leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);

                XDDFDataSource<String> clientNames = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(sheet,
                        new CellRangeAddress(anchor.getRow2()+2, anchor.getRow2()+1+clientDataRequest.size(), 0, 0));

                XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> values = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet,
                        new CellRangeAddress(anchor.getRow2()+2, anchor.getRow2()+1+clientDataRequest.size(), 1, 1));

                XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.BAR, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
                XDDFChartData.Series series = data.addSeries(clientNames, values);
                XDDFLineProperties line = new XDDFLineProperties();
                series.setTitle(null, null);
                data.setVaryColors(false);
                chart.plot(data);

                XDDFBarChartData bar = (XDDFBarChartData) data;
                bar.setBarDirection(BarDirection.BAR);

                workbook.write(file);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){

        }

        return new ByteArrayInputStream(file.toByteArray());

    }
```

It does not have many documentation and samples about the Apache POI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a bar chart you additional need set `AxisCrossBetween` for the value axis, so the value axis crosses the category axis **between** the categories. Else first and last category is exactly on cross points and the bars are only half visible.

In your case:

```
...
XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
leftAxis.setTitle("Value");
leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);

leftAxis.setCrossBetween(org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);
...
```